# Column not appearing in sort option of library view

Tags: 2010

I have a document library in SharePoint 2010 where I am trying to create a view that sorts by Content Type. The column is ticked to display in the view but when I go to the 'sort' option it is not appearing in the drop down menu although for example it does show in the 'filter' drop down menu. Any ideas on how I can get the content type column to display in the sort menu?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1):

Column needs to be indexed

SharePoint enables you to [index columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx) in a list. This is conceptually similar to indexing columns in a database table; however, in the case of SharePoint lists data, the index is maintained by SharePoint instead of SQL Server.

Indexing columns in a list can substantially improve the performance of various query operations, such as queries that use the indexed column, join operations, and ordering operations such as **sorting.** In any list, you can either index a single column or define a composite index on two columns. Composite indexes can enable you to speed up queries across related values. However, like with database indices, list indexing does incur a performance overhead. Maintaining the index adds processing to creating, updating, or deleting items from a list, and the index itself requires storage space. A list instance supports a maximum of 20 indices. Some SharePoint features require indices and cannot be enabled on a list where there is no index slot remaining. You should choose your indexed columns carefully to maximize query performance while avoiding unnecessary overhead.